# React: Can't get a list of component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, reactstrap

On my react class I try to add an Row component to a list for later when I need to list some things. It returns me that error:
`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it`

In another project I have the same feature but different it's works.

I use WebPack and `reactstrap` for Row.

My class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Row, Col, Container} from 'reactstrap';

class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.insert = this.insert.bind(this);
  }

  insert() {
    var list = [];
    list.push(
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <p>Test data</p>
              </Col>
            </Row>);

    return {list};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          {this.insert}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Container } from "reactstrap";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  insert() {
    var list = [];
    list.push(
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <p>Test data</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );

    return list;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>{this.insert()}</Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/j2pm2q1499